# Python: how do I replace all of the same elements in an int array?

Tags: python

I have 1,2,3,6,7,8,1,1,1,6,7,5

What is the syntax for replacing all 1's with ... say.. 0?

for strings its .replace("1", "0")

Comment: Is your "array" actually a list, or is it really an instance of `array.array`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by "array" you mean "list":

```
[0 if e == 1 else e for e in a]
```

where `a` is your list.

If by "array" you mean `array.array`:

```
array.array('i', [0 if e == 1 else e for e in a])
```

Comment: I'd add that single-letter variables in general suck bigtime.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to mention can also use numpy arrays, in which case you can do the following:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,6,7,8,1,1,1,6,7,5])
numpy.where(a==1,0,a)
```

Answer (score 1):

For large lists whith only a few occurrences of `1`, the following is more efficient for changing the list in place than the naive for-loop:

```
i = a.index(1)
try:
    while True:
        a[i] = 0
        i = a.index(1, i + 1)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

This is also less readable than the naive for-loop, so only use it if performance matters.

Answer (score 0):

If your "array" is a "list" you can do a list comprehension:

```
x = [1,2,3,6,7,8,1,1,1,6,7,5]
x = [item if item != 1 else 0 for item in x]
```

This of course creates a new list.  If your list is really big and you don't want to create a new one you could do this instead:

```
for i, item in enumerate(x):
    if item == 1:
        x[i] = 0
```

Or this:

```
for i in xrange(len(x)):
    if x[i] == 1:
        x[i] == 0
```

Comment: @Chong: The first would be memory inefficient but faster, the second two would be slower but more memory efficient.  But again, if it's a Python list these are the ways to do it (except for Sven's answer).  If it's a numpy array then the options are different.